# Unable to hide navigation bar that suddenly appear after popViewController in SearchDisplayCotroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode6, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a problem where a navigation bar suddenly appear after popViewController is called when SearchDisplayCotroller is still active.

[image]

I am implementing a simple tableview with searching capability. Above is my storyboard.

On the first view, i've implemented as per below. So, the navigation bar will be always hidden for the first view.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Button press will push the next table view controller with the below code so that the navigation bar will be visible.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Everything works fine until i implemented the below code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When popViewControllerAnimated:YES while the SearchDisplayController is still active, a weird white navigation bar appears and my viewWillAppear is unable to hide the bar. Is this a bug or is there any way to prevent this bar from appearing?

The gif below may also give you the idea what did happen. Thanks!

[image: Look at the white navigation bar that appeared]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  // To check if searchDisplayController still active
  if ([searchDisplayController isActive]) {
    [searchDisplayController setActive:NO];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try inactivating your `UISearchDisplayController` by calling `setActive:NO animated:NO` before you call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchDisplayController/setActive:animated: